# How to add dynamic List item to another dynamic List in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have a dynamic List for user selection. If the user selects a single item I need to add that dynamic list item to another dynamic List. If the user selects more than 1 item I need to add the selected item to another dynamic List.

**Example:**

```
 List<List<dynamic>> _userDataFull;
 List<List<dynamic>> _userDataSelected;

_userDataFull = [
  ['00000012345’, '0400000048800001', ‘8040'],
  ['00000012345’, '0400000048800002’, ‘8040'],
  ['00000012345’, '0400000048800003’, ‘8040']
];
```

I need to add

```
['00000012345’, '0400000048800001', ‘8040']
```

**from** _userDataFull list **to** _userDataSelected.

And later I might add

```
['00000012345’, '0400000048800001', ‘8040'],
['00000012345’, '0400000048800002’, ‘8040']
```

into  _userDataSelected.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: What is the problem you are having? The code `_userDataSelected = []; _userDataSelected.add(_userDataFull[0]);` should add the first element of `_userDataFull` to `_userDataSelected`.

Comment: @lrn thank you. _userDataSelected = []; works. Forget to assign, but I didn't get assignment like = []; is possible to send me a link to study more?

Comment: Rather than copying all this data around, you should instead have one master list that stores all the data and in all the other list store indices that reference the master list. That way you don't risk mutating data in one place and destroying parity, leading to near-impossible-to-fix bugs.

Comment: @Abion47 thanks. I need to send user selected List to another class for some other work related job from selectedList data values.